# Application crashes when there is no fragment in container.How to avoid this?

Tags: android, android-fragments

My below code is working when there is a fragment but when there is no fragment application crashes....how to avoid this...i can't understand answers given in previous asked queston

```
FloatingActionButton bt_home = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.home);
    bt_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFrame)).commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it crashes? Can you post the stack traces from logcat?

Comment: it gives this error 
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:779)

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `NullPointerException` is thrown when an application attempts to use an object reference that has the `null` value.
So add a `null` check on the `fragment` before using it.
Try this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.myFrame);
if (fragment != null) {
    fm.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: great it is working....But sorry i can't vote you due to double click...and now it is not allowed me to vote...@jayeshsolanki93